# StringEscapeUtils: How to unescape a string except emoji?

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

I am using [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeJava`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-) to escape strings. By which the character: "é" [(LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) transformed as "\u00E9" and "😅" [(SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND COLD SWEAT)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f605/index.htm) transformed as "\uD83D\uDE05". Now if I want to unescape them, they will revert back to their original form. But I want to unescape "\u00E9" to "é" and keep "\uD83D\uDE05" as it is. What should I do so that the emojis are not get escaped but the alphabets are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to "fully unescape" the string, and then re-escape just the emoji. You can do that by detecting the surrogate pairs of characters, using `Character.isLowSurrogate` and `Character.isHighSurrogate`.

For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length());
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
  char c = str.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isHighSurrogate(c) || Character.isLowSurrogate(c)) {
    // Append the escaped character.
    sb.append("\\u");
    sb.append(String.format("%04x", (int) c));
  } else {
    // Append the character as-is.
    sb.append(c);
  }
}
String partlyEscaped = sb.toString();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/KUUVlP)